# PHP Form Submision with jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

This is my code for a jquery mobile application. But the form i created with `php` result is not working. Form is not posting data on submit. I even tried `data-ajax="flase"`.

```
<table id="stock">
<? $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE `product_id` = '1'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $name = $row['name'];
        $chamecal = $row['chamecal'];
        $price = $row['selling_price'];
        $bprice = $row['buying_price'];
        $quantity = $row['quantity'];
        $manufacturer = $row['manufacturer'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $edate = $row['expire'];
        $pid = $row['product_id'];
?>
   <form id="stockupdate" method="post" action="medupdate.php">
    <tr>
        <td><?=$name;?></td>
        <td><?=$chamecal;?></td>
        <td><?=$manufacturer;?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="medbprice" value="<?=$bprice;?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="medprice" value="<?=$price;?>" /></td>
        <td><?=$date;?></td>
        <td><?=$edate;?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="medstock" value="<?=$quantity;?>" /></td>
        <td class="ui-screen-hidden"><input type="text" name="pid" value="<?=$pid;?>" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" title="Update" data-icon="gear" data-theme="f" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?    
    } 
?>
</form>
</table>
```

Values Handler file `medupdate.php`

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php include_once('include/config.php');?>
<?
$pid        = $_POST['pid'];
$medbprice  = $_POST['medbprice'];
$medprice   = $_POST['medprice'];
$medstock   = $_POST['medstock'];

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `products` SET `quantity` = '$medstock', `buying_price` = '$medbprice' , `selling_price` = '$medprice' WHERE `product_id` = '$pid'");

if($sql){
echo 1;
}
?>
```

Comment: We need to see the code where you handle the posted values.  I can't see a single $_POST global variable in the code you have posted.  If the above code is complete, it won't process any of your form data... search Google for 'PHP handle posted values' etc.

Comment: @R. David is this a mobile app or regular website with  jquery mobile supported for responsive ...?

Comment: @SathyaRaj regular website with jquery mobile supported for responsive.

Comment: did you mean to write `data-ajax="false"` or do you really have `="flase"`?

Comment: i tried `data-ajax="false"`. Whatever someone answered my question. The problem was `<form>` inside `<table>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was to hazard a guess, it's because you're placing

```
<form id="stockupdate" method="post" action="medupdate.php">
```

directly within a table element (which is invalid markup). Move this outside your table (before your `<table>`). When you create invalid markup, the browsers engine tries to correct it which can lead to issues like this.

This is what chrome does to your markup:

[image]

Comment: It's a valid point, but he doesn't actually handle the POSTED values anywhere in his code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot follow the html structure, a `form` inside `table` like,

```
<table>
   <form>
     <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </form>
</table>
```

Here is the working code,

**Form php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>



    <body>
        <form id="stockupdate" method="post" action="medupdate.php" data-ajax="false">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="medbprice" value="xxxx" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="medprice" value="yyyyy" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="medstock" value="zzzzzz" /></td>
                    <td class="ui-screen-hidden"><input type="text" name="pid" value="111111" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" title="Update" data-icon="gear" data-theme="f" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**medupdate.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$pid        = $_POST['pid'];
$medbprice  = $_POST['medbprice'];
$medprice   = $_POST['medprice'];
$medstock   = $_POST['medstock'];
echo $pid;
// your database operations
?>
```