# any way to show table data like table without using <table>

Tags: html

Is there any way to show data like table data without using `<table>`
i wanna show data like this table without using `<table>`. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: You can use css and float elements left, with the contents in them.  I do have to ask why though.  The main reason tables still exist is to display tabular data, which is what this is.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css

Comment: i want to use `<form>` in the `<table>` but the `<form>` wont work in the `<table>` thats why i am looking for another way.

Comment: @R.David -- How about a `table` inside a `form` ?? :D

Comment: @R.David: `form`s and `table`s work together just fine.  It sounds like you have a problem and you're trying to solve it by creating a different problem.  Instead of asking how to create the new problem, show the problem you have.

Comment: @David [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377675/php-form-submision-with-jquery-mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377675/php-form-submision-with-jquery-mobile)

here the `<form>` isn't working in `<table>`.But i need `<form>` in the `<table>`. Thats why i am looking for alternative way.

Comment: Instead of `<table><form>...</form></table>` try `<form><table>...</table></form>` :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing something wrong because doing something else wrong didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible. You can create such layout using a div structure by using css float property.

Here is the sample code.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <style type="text/css">
        .trow{
         overflow:auto;
         width:100%;
        }
     .thead{
        font-weight:bold;
       }
     .tcell{
     width:30%;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    border:1px solid

  }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="trow thead">
        <div class="tcell">Name</div>
        <div class="tcell">Chaemacal Amount</div>
        <div class="tcell">Manufacturer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="trow">
        <div class="tcell">Betanol</div>
        <div class="tcell">10mg</div>
        <div class="tcell">Acme</div>
    </div>
    <div class="trow">
        <div class="tcell">Napa Extra</div>
        <div class="tcell">20mg</div>
        <div class="tcell">Beximco Pharma</div>
    </div>
     <div class="trow">
        <div class="tcell">Sergel</div>
        <div class="tcell">20mg</div>
        <div class="tcell">Beximco Pharma</div>
    </div>
     <div class="trow">
        <div class="tcell">Metpho</div>
        <div class="tcell">20mg</div>
        <div class="tcell">Beximco Pharma</div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have also created a JS Fiddle for this.
http://jsfiddle.net/KzzL5/

Comment: awesome Thnx a lot solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS and structure your page accordingly. You have to procedurally fill a DIV containter with each line using PHP cycles (presuming you have a dynamic page - if not then just create those DIVs statically and stylize them). Each "line" should be a DIV that contains row elements stylized to stay on one line next to each other. However if you can use a table I strongly advise you to do so - that's what `<table>` is meant to do.

Edit: Just noticed why you want to do this. Tables and forms work perfectly with each other - just put the table inside a form so the structure looks like this for example:

```
<form action="something.php" method="POST">
<table id="yourTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Field</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="inputField"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```